# Interaction term is insignificant but the interaction plot shows signs of signficance

Tags: anova, data-visualization, interaction

So, I ran an ANOVA on a dataset which contains over 4500 data points. Without getting into too much detail, I was wondering if there is a simple explanation to this:
The p-value for my interaction term A*B is 0.145 => The interaction term is clearly insignificant. Both A and B are categorical variables with 2 levels each. However, when I plot my interaction plot, there's a clear X (i.e.) it is not parallel as one would expect. Is there something I am missing here?

here's the plot-
[image]

Comment: On what do you base your statement that the plot "shows signs" of  significance? How does what you see indicate that? I don't think that hints at 'significance' at all. Clearly being exactly parallel is not going to happen in a sample for a continuous response, even if it's the case for a population. 'Crossing' or 'not crossing' is a function of the design and main effects (or even of noise, perhaps), not of significance - at a given level of estimated interaction I can change the plot from crossing to not crossing by manipulating the main effects without changing the interaction effect..(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... you'd need some estimate of standard error (which I don't see in the plot there) to judge significance.

Comment: As @Glen_b said, you need the standard error. Right now your plots shows what appears to be an undeniable interaction, but it's all relative to the scaling of your y-axis: make it larger, say 0-1, and your interaction visually goes away (without changing any parameter estimates or significance tests, of course).

Comment: I see what you guys mean, but the std dev is 0.00066. Hmm. Does that mean interaction plots won't be helpful at all? we are trying to explain how a process time changes with different levels of our independent variables. Interaction plots seemed to be the best way. Maybe I'm totally wrong :(

Comment: The interaction plot tells you about how big the estimated effect is. That's actually important information! But it's about how much the means change, not about how many standard errors that is, so from the plot you can't say if it's more change than could be explained by random variation. (Information relevant to that judgement could be added to such a plot, but how necessary that is depends on what you're using the plot for.)

Comment: What @Glen_b says. You can add error bars to the dots in your interaction plot to show +/- one standard error (not the raw standard deviation). That would give you a rough idea about the variability in your data. If these bars overlap "a lot", then the interaction term does not actually explain a large proportion of the variance, and will therefore not be significant.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it. Will bounce the idea with my adviser.